# react web dev server not detecting changes to sass files live

Tags: reactjs, react-server

My react app was created with npx create-react-app and is not loading the changes on the local server for changes made in the styles folder.
here is the git repo , 
https://github.com/saulvg1/bottega-final

Comment: Sass files need the scss file ending. Also, you need to install `node-sass` as an additional npm package. See this guide for more information: https://scotch.io/starters/react/adding-sass-to-create-react-app-applications

Comment: thank you , i will try this and report back once done

Comment: My styles continue to change the document correctly. The problem that I am having is that I have to restart the dev server to see any changes to syles on the local server  instead of being able to see them render real time on the live server. I belive that for some reason the watcher does not see or detect changes to the styles in my app so it will not render them on the live server.

Comment: ok I moved my style docs out of their own nested folder inside the styles folder. They are now located in the style folder and when I save it creates the changes now on the live server. Does anyone know why I cannot have the style files within their own nested folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ensure that the webpack.config.js file have the entry with scss or css file type

```
resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx','css','scss']
    },
```